# How to get rid of bunch of ifs

Tags: python

Considering such task:

You are driving a little too fast, and a police officer stops you. Write code to compute the result, encoded as an int value: 0=no ticket, 1=small ticket, 2=big ticket. If speed is 60 or less, the result is 0. If speed is between 61 and 80 inclusive, the result is 1. If speed is 81 or more, the result is 2.

The first hat comes to mind is bunch of ifs like:

```
def caught_speeding(speed):
  if speed > 80:
      return 2
  elif speed > 60:
      return 1          
  else:
      return 0
```

If there a way to achieve same result ith less number of lines?

Comment: Why do you need fewer lines? What you have now is clear and readable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thx for pointing, corrected my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic way to solve the issue is to use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm); you can implement one using the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html):

```
import bisect

def caught_speeding(speed):
   tickets = [60, 80]
   return bisect.bisect_left(tickets, speed)
```

The `bisect_left` function finds the *insertion point* for your speed, in the most efficient way possible (it'll look at *half* of each list to see where your speed should fit in, then half again, until the insertion point is found). For speeds up to 60, you'd insert it in position 0, for speeds between 61 and 80, you insert at position 1, and the rest would be added at the end, at position 2:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> tickets = [60, 80]
>>> bisect.bisect_left(tickets, 60)
0
>>> bisect.bisect_left(tickets, 61)
1
>>> bisect.bisect_left(tickets, 80)
1
>>> bisect.bisect_left(tickets, 81)
2
```

For just 3 different ticket values, this does feel like overkill. Your 3-branch `if-elif-else` construct is more easily understood when coming back to your code at a later time.

Comment: thank you, that is why I asked if there better way. I haven't read about bisect before

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from bisect import bisect_left
>>> bisect_left([60, 80], 50)
0
>>> bisect_left([60, 80], 60)
0
>>> bisect_left([60, 80], 70)
1
>>> bisect_left([60, 80], 80)
1
>>> bisect_left([60, 80], 90)
2
```

So you could have

```
def caught_speeding(speed):
    bisect_left([60, 80], speed)
```

Answer (score 0):

While not as fast as using `bisect` since it does a linear search, the following makes few assumptions about the intervals or the order in which they are specified (nor about kind of values are being compared, which could be integers, floats, dates, etc):

```
import sys

def caught_speeding(speed, intervals):
    for i, interval in enumerate(intervals):
        if interval[0] <= speed <= interval[1]:
            return i
    return None  # wasn't in any interval

speed_ranges = [[0, 60], [61, 80], [81, sys.maxint]]

print(caught_speeding(45, speed_ranges))  # --> 0
print(caught_speeding(65, speed_ranges))  # --> 1
print(caught_speeding(90, speed_ranges))  # --> 2
```